# Why did this transaction not win? Same block, higher gas?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to understand why this transaction failed, even though it's in the same block as this other transaction, both trying to do the same trade and this one has higher gas than the other - yet the other still won?

Is it because the failed one may have some errors in the input data? I did notice the successful one has a little note saying "(Also found 1 other dropped Txn #1 with the same `from` account nonce)", would it have anything to do with that?

Failed tx:
[image]

Successful tx:
[image]

Comment: we can't say much about this without knowing the contract address

Comment: @flygoing Ah, sorry about that - here they are:

Successful: Contract 0x94b3f35a7a3a24d791504f45bf2e137fa7a5486e, Failed: Contract 0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819 (etherdelta_2) . It looks like the successful one is using a custom / privately made contract .

Comment: @Tim can you provide the links to etherscan? All data is public so there's no point in blocking out the tx hash

Comment: @MiguelMota - Good point, here they are: Success - 0xb96fbe7915020ce8173cf4e65f4905d89da0dc5ba8afab6842e7434afbac2b05 , Failed: 0x00100cd25da1aefa45fc303a5e349fa1467a8ac4c57beeca267ec78b435e0871

Answer (score 1):

0x00100cd25da1aefa45fc303a5e349fa1467a8ac4c57beeca267ec78b43‌​5e0871 transaction failed because of etherdelta function failed. It have nothing to do with gas price, this transaction was calling trade method on etherdelta contract and due to the way how etherdelta works(having orders offchain) it rejects transactions when someone tries to fill order that was already filled. So if multiple people try to access same order simultaneity only one of transactions will go through.

Comment: Alright so if I got my order in first, it would still work with low gas? Also that transaction doesn't look like it even uses etherdelta's smart contract, it's using their own smart contract, so how does that work, if they aren't using the smart contract - but I am, shouldn't I be the one getting the order?